# Como criar uma versão simplificada do jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

O jsFiddle usa json para salvar o CSS/HTML, Javascript/JQuery? Provavelmente esse `json` é salvo em um banco. A série `4fh0xdpc` seria o ID no banco.

`http://jsfiddle.net/`**`4fh0xdpc`**`/`

A cada update é gerado um número após esse id.

`http://jsfiddle.net/4fh0xdpc/`**`1`**`/`

Ou ele simplesmente envia o arquivo .json no servidor e salva (cria-se uma pasta)?
por exemplo:

- pasta `4fh0xdpc`
  para o primeiro projeto criado.

*caso houver update:*

- pasta `4fh0xdpc` com subdiretório `1` (sempre variando)

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que o usuário poderá construir um formulário dinamicamente (incluir perguntas, validação de cada pergunta, gerar o banco do formulário automaticamente etc). Parte do sistema está desenvolvido (já estou gerando o .json com todas as perguntas, número, etc). Porém, gostaria de fazer algo a mais: salvar o projeto para posteriormente ser mexido pelo mesmo usuário ou um outro.
Há alguma dica para implementar essa parte? Queria seguir os moldes do `jsfiddle`, caso houver alguma dica boa, estou aberto para dicas.

Comment: Seria melhor perguntar pra eles.

Comment: Engenharia reversa em cima de uma ferramenta que não temos acesso ao código fonte, é algo que eu diria fora do escopo (?)

Comment: estava pensando em fazer algo do tipo, mas não é pra desenvolvedor. é construir um formulário dinamicamente (monto o .json no front e envio para o servidor montar o formulário e devolver ele para download). queria fazer semelhante ao jsfiddle - fazer update, algo colaborativo).

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Se vocês tiverem uma dica por onde começar, rsrs. Estou trabalhando recentemente com javascript (4 meses). Não queria copiar, mas pegar a mesma idéia deles (se foi implementado do jeito que eu falei).

Comment: Acontece que isso é muito relativo, existem n maneiras de se atingir o mesmo objetivo, tem que haver todo um estudo de caso, eu pessoalmente li a sua duvida no comentário e entendi bulhufas.... tente explicar melhor o seu objetivo na própria pergunta, quem sabe não fique mais entendivel

Comment: modifiquei o post. Talvez dê para entender o que estou querendo.

Comment: O jsFiddle foi [desenvolvido pelo Oskar e pelo Piotr](https://github.com/jsfiddle), na altura membros ativos da comunidade do MooTools e tem uma [API para criar jsFiddles já preenchidos](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/). Que funcionalidades queres ter? Somente o criar novos urls para novos formulários? e queres manter a ideia no url de `base/versão` como no teu exemplo `4fh0xdpc/1/`? Queres também que dê para preencher com json? que linguagem tens no servidor?

Comment: Uma pergunta interessante, mas está fora de foco. Embora o JsFiddle possa ser uma fonte de inspiração, tente pensar numa estrutura que atenda sua solução, depois faça perguntas específicas sobre essa arquitetura. Por exemplo, primeiro você precisa definir quais informações serão editadas pelo usuário na tela, depois como elas serão transmitidas para o servidor, depois como elas serão identificadas (hash único?), persistidas (tabelas), e versionadas (novas versões 2, 3, 4...), depois precisa se preocupar com permissão e segurança e por aí vai. Não necessariamente as coisas são nessa ordem.

Comment: ["gostaria de fazer algo a mais: salvar o projeto para posteriormente ser mexido pelo mesmo usuário ou um outro"] só que o JSFiddle já faz isso rsrsr

Comment: O que te interessa é o lado do servidor? Por exemplo, como salvar, como compor as URLs, etc.? Ou a funcionalidade do jsfiddle em si?

Comment: @Sergio gostaria de criar as urls, e exibir o conteúdo (tenho um arquivo .json que monto no server e gero dinamicamente os inputs populados no html).
- bfavaretto sim algo do tipo, a pessoa entra na url caso algo tenha sido salvo.

Answer (score 3):

Testar ou debugar um pequeno script pode ser uma tarefa desnecessariamente trabalhosa. Afinal de contas, é necessário criar uma nova página html, escrever sua marcação, inserir scripts, adicionar bibliotecas, salvar e, então, testá-la em algum browser para acompanhar o resultado. Tudo para, muitas vezes, chegar à conclusão de que o grande problema do código era um ponto-e-vírgula ausente ou um seletor mal identificado.

A jsFiddle surgiu dessa necessidade de testar scripts rapidamente. Desenvolvida originalmente para MooTools, a ferramenta foi se expandindo aos poucos, e hoje oferece suporte às principais bibliotecas Javascript do mercado, como MooTools, jQuery, YUI, Prototype, Dojo, Glow, Processing, ExtJS, Raphael e Right JS. Sua interface é simples e intuitiva, bastando selecionar a biblioteca desejada e preencher os campos de XHTML, CSS e Javascript com os dados desejados para testar um script. Clicando no botão “Run”, é possível ver o script em ação, sem a necessidade de criar novos arquivos ou de utilizar vários programas para visualizá-lo.

Aqui está o que você precisa para iniciar seu projeto. É um clone simplificado do `jsFiddle` criado por **nwoike**.

[DOWNLOAD](https://github.com/nwoike/Diddle)

> COMO FICA?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]